Can someone determine time complexity of this LeetCode solution I made?
I wrote a solution to the problem linked below but I'm not sure about its time complexity. I was thinking it was quadratic but it passed within 0 ms when I submitted, so it might be linear idk. I would be happy if someone with more experience explained me.
https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/description/
Here's my solution (written in C):
#include <stdbool.h>

struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
 };

int maxDepth(struct TreeNode* root) {
    if (!root)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    int leftHeight = 1 + maxDepth(root->left);
    int rightHeight = 1 + maxDepth(root->right);

    if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
        return leftHeight;
    else
        return rightHeight;
}

bool isBalanced(struct TreeNode* root) {
    
    if (!root)
    {
        return true;
    }

    int leftHeight = maxDepth(root->left);
    int rightHeight = maxDepth(root->right);

    int diff = leftHeight - rightHeight;

    if (diff == 0 || diff == 1 || diff == -1){
        return isBalanced(root->left) && isBalanced(root->right);
    }

    return false; 
}

Analyzing the functions individually, I know it costs linear time to calculate the max depth of a Tree, and since I'm calling it for every node of the tree I thought it would be linear. However, it got a pretty good runtime when submitted, so I'd like to know how that happened.


I know it costs linear time to calculate the max depth of a Tree

Correct

since I'm calling it for every node of the tree I thought it would be linear

The combination is not linear. It is O(log) for balanced trees:
The number of nodes visited for a single execution of isBalanced at the root (without recursive call of isBalanced) is  (count one for the isBalanced visit of the root, and then the complete subtree visits that the recursive maxDepth calls make). The number of nodes visited by the recursive isBalanced call (only, without further recursion) is −1 (all except the root). At the next recursion level this is −3 (all except the top two levels), etc. Continuing the worst case scenario (where the tree is perfectly balanced, with  being one less than an integer power of 2) we get:
       + −1 + −3 + −7 + ... + (+1)/2, a sum with log2(+1) terms, or
      −(2⁰−1) + −(2¹−1) + −(2²−1) + −(2³−1) + ... + (+1)/2, a sum with log2(+1) terms
The subtracted powers of two form a geometric series (2⁰ + 2¹ + 2² + 2³ + ... + 2log(+1)−1), and sum up to , so we get:
      log(+1) −  + log(+1) = (+1)log(+1) − 
...which is O(log).
For non-balanced trees, the first detected unbalance will cause the recursion tree to unwind without any further recursive calls. So the time complexity will in that case not be worse than above.
For practical inputs, time complexity is not the only factor for what the actual running time will be. As you have noticed, an implementation can still perform tasks fast enough for concrete inputs even when the time complexity may not be the optimal one.
You could reach linear time complexity by a bottom up approach where you bubble up the depths that you have calculated for subtrees so they don't need to be calculated more than once for each node.

@renanmatulianes, any feedback to this answer?
